# Sysctl parameter change after every reboot

Tags: debian, systemd, sysctl

I have found that the value of `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_count` variable change every time i reboot the system. Did any one have an explanation for that?

Comment: Can you explain more details, e.g: How do you set that value? How is the value change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As one can lookup in [`Documentation/networking/nf_conntrack-sysctl.txt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/nf_conntrack-sysctl.txt), this variable is not really a `sysctl` variable to tweak system behavior, but to read-only variable telling you something about kernel state, in this case:

```
nf_conntrack_count - INTEGER (read-only)
     Number of currently allocated flow entries.
```

This number changes over time, since the number of allocated flow entries (connections, the `conntrack` subsystem is tracking at the moment) changes.  You could try it out by establishing a bunch of connections to some server and look how the value changes.